# how to add buttons to Gallery in Universal Android Image Loader?

Tags: android, gallery

I am working on a sample project and I am using the Universal Image Loader. UIL is great but I want to modify something, I just want to put buttons like Next / Previous in the Gallery.

But I can't see my Buttons view in the Gallery.

Here is the XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gallery Demo"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    />
    <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:spacing="100px"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    android:scrollX="100px"
    />
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_marginTop="5px"
     >
     <Button
     android:text="Previous"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
     android:onClick="onClick"
      />
      <Button
     android:text="Next"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/btnNext"
     android:onClick="onClick"
      />

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

It seems that the Gallery view is filling the whole space of the screen. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Where you want to put this button, buttom of the Gallery.

Comment: at the bottom / top of the gallery. it doesn't really matter. is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your I`magePagerAdapter extends BaseAdapter` `imageview` `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` , It may be `Fill_parent` or `wrap_content.`

If it `wrap_content` then if you image is big then it show in full screen.

Thanks

Comment: so what is the proper layout_width and height to use? fill_parent? match_parent? wrap_content?

Comment: it didn't work either, i think this has nothing to with ImagePagerAdapter layout. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Better to use  android:layout_weight="0.6" in <Gallery />

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: I think, you use ViewPager not Gallery.

Comment: why you use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager in layout

Comment: no, i didn't use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager as my layout. you said you want me to show you the ImagePagerAdapter layout.